# How do I get the dropdown datatype for members to print to the page?

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I was wondering how I would make a html drop down list from the values in a datatype? It needs to have the prevalue as the name and the associated ID number as the value.

[image]

Comment: In a lot of cases I would recommend against using the Umbraco dropdown list; it is not user editable (unless the user is a developer), if you remove a value all of the dropdowns using the value will potentially break, the IDs of the prevalues aren't necessarily the same between Umbraco instances, and it is difficult to get the values from the list using code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
@using System.Xml.XPath
@{ 
  XPathNodeIterator iterator = umbraco.library.GetPreValues(1124);
  iterator.MoveNext();
  XPathNodeIterator preValues = iterator.Current.SelectChildren("preValue", "");
}

    <select name="codeTheme">
        @while (preValues.MoveNext())
        {
            string preValue = preValues.Current.Value;
            string id = preValues.Current.GetAttribute("id", "");

            <option value="@id" @(member.GetValue("codeTheme").ToString() == id ? "selected" : "")>@preValue</option>
        }
    </select>
```

You just need to change the ID number in the `GetPreValues(xxxx)` to the id of the datatype you are targeting. To find this navigate the to datatype in the Umbraco back-end and take the number from the URL.

"codeTheme" needs to be changed to name of the property in the memebership area.